# Integrated Version Control for Visual Studio

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

What version control systems have you used to manage projects developed with Visual Studio (2005)? What would you recommend and Why? What limitations have you found with your top rated version control system?

Answer (score 6):

[Covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857/what-do-you-use-as-a-good-alternative-to-team-system) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073/alternatives-to-visual-sourcesafe-that-integrate-with-visual-studio) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832/lightweight-source-control)

[Search for 'Visual Studio Source Control' sorted by Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?s=visual%20studio%20source%20control&sort=votes)

Answer (score 0):

I've used SourceGear's Vault - it integrates nicely with VS as well as with FogBugz.

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information to make good recommendations.  For example, ClearCase is amazingly powerful but unless you're in a decent sized development studio it would be immensly wasteful, and likely reduce overall productivity.

For personal work I like [SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/), but that's mainly personal taste and being familar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, *don't* learn Git - after you learn it, you realize how every other SCM is trash and you'll hate every minute you have to use Perforce, SVN, or (God help you) VSS/TFS

Answer (score 0):

I used to use SourceSafe, but have made the switch to Subversion and will never go back.

I use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) with [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com). VisualSVN provides the IDE integration with Visual Studio so it feels much like SourceSafe.

The first big benefit is that it works very well over HTTP so I can work with a distributed team. I host my files with [CVSDude](http://www.cvsdude.com).

Secondly, the fact that you don't need to check out a file before editing is a huge benefit, particularly when working with files that sit outside the Visual Studio project.

Thirdly, my source code actually feels safe. Ironically it never did with SourceSafe...